# Swift Crashlytics without cocoapods and fabric API Key not showing dashboard or any data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift4, firebase-crash-reporting

I have implemented firebase Crashlytics in my swift projects without cocoapods. I have done the following task so far. But still, not getting anything on the dashboard.

1. Created project in firebase console. Downloaded the plist file and added to project.
2. Added the firebase library all with Firebase.h header file. Then added the header with an Obj-c bridge header file from settings. Also fabric and Crashlytics library.
3. Added the run script.
4. In `appdelegate`, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` , added these 3 lines.

   ```
   FirebaseApp.configure()
   Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
   Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
   ```
5. In a viewcontroller, added the following line, run on the simulator, make a crash, relaunch the apps. So that I can expect it to upload on the dashboard. Nothing found in the log, just see firebase enabled. Crashlytics version ...

   ```
   Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
   ```
6. From project settings i set ,  Debug Inforation Format : DWARF with dSYM File

But I see nothing on the dashboard. I don't use any API key in my Plist, I just using the plist in my project. What could be my problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the Firebase logs in Xcode tell you anything?

Comment: Yes: i launched the app without xcode. Had a crash programmatically and re-launch the from xcode to see log. I see a message "[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission ....."  and [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful. But in dashboard, i see nothing.

Comment: So, its probably not a linking issue because the app wouldn't build if that were the case. Did you generate the `GoogleService-Info.plist` for your specific application in Firebase, correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the issue is. You're probably running in the Simulator with the debugger attached.

> Crashlytics can’t capture crashes if your build attaches a debugger at launch.

Docs for forcing a crash: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash

To fix this, go to your app in the Simulator **w/o the debugger** attached and reproduce your crash. You should see your crash in the Firebase console.

Comment: ok. For testing now i am getting the crash on dashboard.  In the project : I set Debug - DWARF with DYSM , Release - DWARF.  And in appdelegate i set , Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true. What should i do for Live app.Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = false ?  and Project Debug Information Debug - DWARF with DYSM , Release - DWARF with DYSM , both same  ?

Comment: So you saw the crash in the dashboard, right? Sounds like you're good. I don't think its related to `DEBUG` or `RELEASE` configurations (I was wrong about that). It has to do w/ the debugger being attached to the Simulator/app process.

Comment: @JamshedAlam I don't think you need `Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true`. for this. This is a debugger issue. Did my answer solve your question?

Comment: Just later of the post, I was getting the crash when using using the debug true in w/o mode.  When i will upload the app, what about the debug value and project settings ? Do i need to use this and Release - DWARF with DYSM ? Could you please ensure it ?

Comment: Jamshed, that is a different question than what you originally asked. I don't think you can submit a binary to the App Store that's built in `DEBUG` mode. Maybe you can ask a separate question for the Configuration and symbolicated files?